# Jupyter kernel dies when importing Tensorflow, trouble with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I use Anaconda version 4.5.8 with Python 3.6.6. After installing tensorflow by using the following commands from the tensorflow website:

```
conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5
activate tensorflow
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

I've done as they have instructed and yet my kernel dies whenever I `import tensorflow as tf` in my Jupyter notebook.

I've also looked at other solutions on this website and uninstalled all of tensorflow and installed `pip install tensorflow==1.5`. No matter my kernel still dies.

I've created another new environment in Anaconda and installed `pip install tensorflow==1.51` and still my kernel dies. I've downgraded to `python2.7`, and my kernel dies.

I've downgraded my tensorflow and my python and the kernel still ends up dead. Can anyone find a solution to this?

Edit: Rechecked solutions again, others don't work.
Edit: Tried environment changing as commenter suggested, didn't work.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Just a quick guess, maybe you can try to change your env name to something different.

Comment: Any error messages from console on why the kernel died?

Comment: @AstroBen Windows. CPU only

Comment: @lincr Done it multiple times, I'll give it another go.

Comment: @swiftg No. "kernel appears to have died, it will restart shortly"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (although it worked problem-free previously): I could do anything in Python as long as I didn't use tensorflow. Which is a bit difficult if you're trying to study convolutional networks.
Installing tensorflow 1.5 (with pip3) instead of the current tensorflow did not help me either, but after trying [conda instead of pip](https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-installing-tensorflow-using-pip-for-performance-sake-5854f9d9eb0c) it worked like a charm!